# Removing any number from a string in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following variable:

```
let dropdownValue = 'Porsche (1)';
```

I am now trying to remove the end part of that variable using the following replace function:

```
dropdownValue = dropdownValue.replace(' (' + /[0-9]/g + ')','');
```

As you can see I am trying to remove this whole section of the string  `(1)`. I need it to remove it regardless of what number is in there so from 0 to ∞.

Any idea where I am going wrong here as this doesn't seem to be working? I tried following one of the questions posted on here before using the following replace function but I have had not luck as nothing is replaced.

Comment: You are mixing a string with a regex expression.  Try simply `replace(/\([0-9]+\)/g, '')` and see if that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be your replace code:

```
dropdownValue = dropdownValue.replace(/ \(\d+\)/g,'');
```

Comment: Question states the number can be 0 to infinity.  This currently will only remove 0-9.

Comment: Probably `\d+` rather than `[0-9]`, so that 1) You're using the semantic "digit" token, and 2) It handles more than one digits.

Comment: Moreover, there **has** to be a dupetarget for this.

Answer (score 0):

Different approach: split by space and remove the last part:

```js
console.log(
  'Porsche (1)'.split(' ').slice(0,-1).join(' ')
)
```

This preserves possible inner numbers (car model, etc.) and leaves no spaces around.

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted, because it does the trick.  It could be simplified by splitting on ' ('  :  `'Porsche (1)'.split(' (')[0]`.